# Plot3D unable to understand input function

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm attempting to plot the Wigner Function of the Morse Oscillator defined as

```
f[λ_, m_, n_, y_, k_] = 
    (2/Pi)N1[λ, n] N1[λ, m]ξ^(2λ - m - n - 1)* 
    Sum[Sum[b[λ, m, r]b[λ, n, s]ξ^(r + s)* 
            BesselK[m - n - r + s + 2*I*k, ξ], {s, 0, n}], {r, 0, m}]
```

where

```
N1[λ_, n_] =  Sqrt[(2*λ - 2 n - 1)*Gamma[n + 1]/Gamma[2*λ - n]]

b[λ_, n_, j_] = (-1)^j*(1/j!)*Gamma[2*λ - n]/(Gamma[2*λ - 
                         2 n + j]*Gamma[n - j + 1])

ξ = 2*λ*Exp[-y]
```

I found that if I use the function `f` in Mathematica's `Plot3D`, I get an error:
[image]

However, if I first evaluate `f[1,0,0,y,k]`, and then plug the result into `Plot3D`, I get:

[image]

[image]

Why does Mathematica have trouble plotting `f[1,0,0,y,k]` if I plug it directly into `Plot3D`, but has no trouble if I first evaluate `f[1,0,0,y,k]`? Is there a way for Mathematica to understand `Plot3D[f[1,0,0,y,k],{y,-3,3},{k,-3,3}]`? I want Mathematica to plot the function automatically without me having to first evaluate the function and then copy and paste the output into `Plot3D`. For example, one thing I'd like to do is `Manipulate[Plot3D[f[5,n,n,y,k],{y,-3,3},{k,-3,3}],{n,0,4,1}]`.

Thanks.

$\bf{\large{Edit}}$

Interestingly, for

```
f[1, 0, 0, 1., 1.]
```

I get:

```
0.468399 DifferenceRoot[   Function[{\[FormalY]$, \[FormalN]$}, {4 (-1 - \[FormalN]$ + 
      0) (-\[FormalN]$ + 0) 1^2 \[FormalY]$[\[FormalN]$] - 
   2 (-1 - \[FormalN]$ + 0) (\[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) + 
      2 \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) + \[FormalN]$^3 E^(2 1.) + 
      2 I \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 1. + 
      2 I \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) 1. + \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.)
        0 + \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) 0 - 2 E^(2 1.) 0 - 
      5 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0 - 3 \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) 0 - 
      4 I E^(2 1.) 1. 0 - 4 I \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 1. 0 - 
      2 E^(2 1.) 0 0 - 2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0 0 + 
      2 E^(2 1.) 0^2 + 
      2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0^2 - \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.)
        r - \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) r + 2 E^(2 1.) 0 r + 
      2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0 r + 2 E^(2 1.) + 
      4 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) + 2 \[FormalN]$^2 E^(2 1.) + 
      4 I E^(2 1.) 1. + 4 I \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 1. + 
      2 E^(2 1.) 0 + 2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0 - 2 E^(2 1.) 0 - 
      2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) 0 - 2 E^(2 1.) r - 
      2 \[FormalN]$ E^(2 1.) r - 2 \[FormalN]$ 1^2 + 
      2 0 1^2) \[FormalY]$[
     1 + \[FormalN]$] + (1 + \[FormalN]$) E^(
    2 1.) (-\[FormalN]$ + 2 0 - 2 1) (4 + 7 \[FormalN]$ + 
      3 \[FormalN]$^2 + 4 I 1. + 4 I \[FormalN]$ 1. + 2 0 + 
      2 \[FormalN]$ 0 - 8 0 - 6 \[FormalN]$ 0 - 4 I 1. 0 - 
      2 0 0 + 2 0^2 - 2 r - 2 \[FormalN]$ r + 2 0 r + 4 1 + 
      2 \[FormalN]$) \[FormalY]$[
     2 + \[FormalN]$] + (1 + \[FormalN]$) (2 + \[FormalN]$) E^(
    2 1.) (-1 - \[FormalN]$ + 2 0 - 2 1) (-\[FormalN]$ + 2 0 - 
      2 1) \[FormalY]$[3 + \[FormalN]$] == 0, \[FormalY]$[0] == 
  0, \[FormalY]$[1] == BesselK[2 I 1. + 0 - 0 - r, 2 E^-1.]/(
  Gamma[1 + 0] Gamma[-2 0 + 2 1]), \[FormalY]$[2] == 
  BesselK[2 I 1. + 0 - 0 - r, 2 E^-1.]/(
   Gamma[1 + 0] Gamma[-2 0 + 2 1]) + (
   2 E^-1. 0 BesselK[1 + 2 I 1. + 0 - 0 - r, 
     2 E^-1.])/((2 0 - 2 1) Gamma[1 + 0] Gamma[-2 0 + 2 1])}]][1]
```

However, for

```
f[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I get:

```
(4*BesselK[2*I, 2/E])/(E*Pi)
```

Comment: Please post copyable code.

Comment: If pre-evaluation works, an easy workaround should be `Plot3D[Evaluate@f[1,0,0,y,k], {y,-3,3}, {k,-3,3}]`. While that doesn't answer your question, it might solve your problem.

Comment: In the signature of f there should be a _ following the m.  This may not be your problem of course.

Comment: BTW, what do you get for `f[1,0,0,1.,1.]`?

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for the workaround. It definitely helps solve my problem. For f[1,0,0,1.,1.], I get a really ugly mess. I'm not sure how to format it in the comment (plus it may be too long), so I'll put it in an edit in my question.

Comment: I'm afraid your definitions don't work for me as is.  You might want to define `\[Xi][\[Lambda]_, y_] := 2*\[Lambda]*Exp[-y];` and update the use of `\[Xi]` in the def. of `f`.  You might also want `:=` instead of `=` in the defs. of the other functions.  Finally, if you use `=`, you can put a `;` after the definition to suppress unnecessary output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 2):

### SetDelayed

Just inserted some SetDelayed assignments. Thought the 3rd one (xsi) gave reason for messages. It works fine now.

```
Clear@"`*"

N1[λ_, n_] := 
 Sqrt[(2*λ - 2 n - 1)*Gamma[n + 1]/Gamma[2*λ - n]]

b[λ_, n_, j_] := (-1)^j*(1/j!)*
  Gamma[2*λ - n]/(Gamma[2*λ - 2 n + j]*
     Gamma[n - j + 1])
ξ[λ_, y_] := 2*λ*Exp[-y]


f[λ_, m_, n_, y_, k_] := (2/Pi)*N1[λ, n] *
  N1[λ, m]*ξ[λ, y]^(2 λ - m - n - 1)*
  Sum[Sum[b[λ, m, r]*
     b[λ, n, s]*ξ[λ, y]^(r + s)*
     BesselK[m - n - r + s + 2*I*k, 2*λ*Exp[-y]], {s, 0, 
     n}], {r, 0, m}]

Plot3D[f[1, 0, 0, y, k], {y, -3, +3}, {k, -3, +3}]
```

### Manipulate

Now your Manipulate code gives:

Example

[image: wigner function]